# Remove component that was added in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, components, cardlayout, removeall

i have card layout that have this JPanel :

CardLayout :

1. panelEntry
2. panelRecord

In panelRecord, I add component video capture.
This code is the addition of video capture component:

```
panelRecord.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, graph.asComponent());
```

`graph.asComponent()` is component from DSJ (Direct Show JavaWrapper), and i dont now what type this component.

When I move back to panelEntry layout (because i use card layout), all functions in panelEntry be slow. I think, because it was still have panelRecord video capture active.
I want to remove the component in panelRecord earlier. How?

Please help, thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried `CardLayout#removeLayoutComponent()`? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

A Container has a method to remove a component

```
public void remove(Component comp)
```

> Removes the specified component from this container. This method also notifies the layout manager  to remove the component from this container's layout via the `removeLayoutComponent` method.

Create a variable for the component to remove

```
compToRemove = graph.asComponent()
```

Add it

```
panelRecord.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, graph.asComponent());
```

Remove it when you like

```
panelRecord.remove(compToRemove);
```

You need to update the graphics at each step

Comment: `I think, because it was still have panelRecord video capture active`. Then stop the video capture when you switch panels.